# 2 tables with same attributes, how to select the one i want?

Tags: mysql

i got following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` AS a, products_description, categories_description JOIN products_to_categories AS b WHERE a.products_id=b.products_id AND b.categories_id=2 ORDER BY `a`.`products_date_added` DESC LIMIT 4"; 

mysql_select_db('dewaren_shop');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    echo "<a href=/\"{$row['gm_url_keywords']}\"/\"{$row['gm_url_keywords']}\"/><img src=\"{$row['products_image']}\"/><a/>  <br> ".
        "{$row['products_short_description']}  <br> ";
} 
mysql_close($conn);
```

i am selecting 3 tables from my mysql. I need an URL from the products_description table and one from the categories_description table. The problem is in both tables the URL is called "gm_url_keywords". How can i pick the URL from categories table for the first link and the URL from the products table for the second one?

Comment: The easy way: stop using `SELECT *`.

Comment: well that wouldn´t change anything in this case. Even if i would just select the fields i need, both would be called "gm_url_keywords". So not the answer i was looking for

Comment: use aliases for the columns in your select clause

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention them explicitely. Instead of saying `select *` specify the column names explicitely using column alias like below

```
SELECT p.URL as products_URL,
pd.URL as products_description_URL,
cd.URL as categories_description_URL

FROM `products` p, 
JOIN products_description pd
JOIN categories_description cd
```